# In ACF Pro, how do I show the other fields referenced from a Post Object?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In Wordpress\ACF Pro, I have a Field Group called Deliveries. It has a Repeater with a Post Object field that connected to a Field Group called Customers. How do I show the Customer data fields in my output page?

More details: The Customer Field Group has the Customer as the post name, plus fields for address, phone, city, zip. The Deliveries FG has a Repeater, with a Customer Post Object linking back to the Customer FG. The Deliveries FG has fields for special instructions, delivery status, alternate address and so on. The Delivery FG uses a repeater because I want to create a post for that day's deliveries with all of the Customers to be served that day.

When I build the template in Bricks Builder, I can get the Customer PO and the Deliveries fields to show. That's it. Even though the fields for the Customer are referenced, they do not show. Obviously, I am missing some connection here, and I do not know what it is.

I've used BingAI to try to answer the question, and it writes PHP for me. I don't know PHP. I do have the Theme Code Pro plugin, and it writes the following PHP for me.

```
<?php if ( have_rows( 'customer_delivery' ) ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_rows( 'customer_delivery' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
        <?php $customer_po = get_sub_field( 'customer_po' ); ?>
        <?php if ( $customer_po ) : ?>
            <?php $post = $customer_po; ?>
            <?php setup_postdata( $post ); ?> 
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php the_sub_field( 'special_instructions' ); ?>
        <?php the_sub_field( 'reason' ); ?>
        <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'pick_up_check' ) == 1 ) : ?>
            <?php // echo 'true'; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php // echo 'false'; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( get_sub_field( 'alternate_address' ) == 1 ) : ?>
            <?php // echo 'true'; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php // echo 'false'; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php the_sub_field( 'temporary_address' ); ?>
        <?php the_sub_field( 'items' ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php // No rows found ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The theme code for the Customer fields is:

```
<?php the_field( 'address' ); ?>
<?php the_field( 'address_2' ); ?>
<?php the_field( 'city' ); ?>
<?php the_field( 'zip' ); ?>
<?php the_field( 'phone' ); ?>
```

From the Bing answers, I am able to deduce that I need to insert code referencing the Customer FG fields in the section referencing the *Customer PO* field, but I'll be damned if I know where. One of the reasons I use page builders like Bricks or Oxygen is because I don't know PHP.

If anyone out there knows what step I missed, or how to fix my problem, I would be grateful.